# Issue in autorotating UIViecontrollers in UINavigationcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, autorotate

I'd downloaded a sample from [this tutorial](http://www.disalvotech.com/blog/app-development/iphone/ios-6-rotation-solution/) site about rotating the viewcontrollers in navingation controllers.

That sample project functionality

- Support potrait for FirstviewController
- Support all orientations for second view controller(pushed from first VC)

What I need is,

- FirstviewController should support all orientations
- Second view controller(pushed from first VC) should support potrait alone.

What I did was, just swapped the codes in the view controllers

In first view controller

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate  
{
    return YES;
}
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation 
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

In Second view controller and

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

But, both the view controllers are rotating.

How can I fix this issue? Any suggestions, please share.

**----EDIT----**

If I rotate the simulator to landscape before pushing, second VC is also in landscape view.

If I push to second vc in potrait, the second VC is in potrait mode(it's not rotating if I rotate there.)

I put log in customNavigationcontroller `NSLog(@"self.topViewController.class %@",self.topViewController.class);`. It's only logging for firstview controller after pushing to second vc it's not logging

Comment: Are you sure you use an `CustomNavigationController` object ?

Comment: @MichaëlAzevedo,  yes I'm using CustomNavigationController, just downloaded the source from http://www.disalvotech.com/blog/app-development/iphone/ios-6-rotation-solution/

Comment: Add some log in your `CustomNavigationController`'s `shouldAutorotate`and `supportedInterfaceOrientations` method in order to know what is the topViewController and the value returned.

Comment: @MichaëlAzevedo, I put log in customNavigationcontroller `NSLog(@"self.topViewController.class %@",self.topViewController.class);` It's only logging for firstview controller after pushing to second vc it's not logging.

Comment: Well, that's an issue, you should have logs too. Does you navigation stack only include these two view controllers and the navigation controller is your entry point, or do you have others view controllers ?

Comment: @MichaëlAzevedo, I'm having two VCs, first VC is the root view controller of navigation controller. I'm pushing to second VC from it, Log is happening only for first VC. ie, that method in customnavigationcotroller not even gets called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest an easier way to solve this issue.

Select your project's target and configure it like this:

[image: Select your target and set this]

Then go to Appdelegate.m and paste:

```
- (UIViewController*)topViewController {
return [self topViewControllerWithRootViewController:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController];
}

- (UIViewController*)topViewControllerWithRootViewController:(UIViewController*)rootViewController {
// Handling UITabBarController
if ([rootViewController isKindOfClass:[UITabBarController class]]) {
    UITabBarController* tabBarController = (UITabBarController*)rootViewController;
    return [self topViewControllerWithRootViewController:tabBarController.selectedViewController];
}
// Handling UINavigationController
else if ([rootViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
    UINavigationController* navigationController = (UINavigationController*)rootViewController;
    return [self topViewControllerWithRootViewController:navigationController.visibleViewController];
}
// Handling Modal views
else if (rootViewController.presentedViewController) {
    UIViewController* presentedViewController = rootViewController.presentedViewController;
    return [self topViewControllerWithRootViewController:presentedViewController];
}
// Handling UIViewController's added as subviews to some other views.
else 
{
    for (UIView *view in [rootViewController.view subviews])
    {
        id subViewController = [view nextResponder];    // Key property which most of us are unaware of / rarely use.
        if ( subViewController && [subViewController isKindOfClass:[UIViewController class]])
        {
            return [self topViewControllerWithRootViewController:subViewController];
        }
    }
    return rootViewController;
    }
}
```

Now here's the fun part.

Put this method on AppDelegate.m,you can decide the orientation of every controller here.

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {

id presentedViewController = [self topViewController];
NSString *className = presentedViewController ? NSStringFromClass([presentedViewController class]) : nil;

if (window && [className isEqualToString:@"FirstViewController"]) { //FirstviewController should support all orientations
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
} else {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait; //Second view controller(pushed from first VC) should support potrait alone.
}
}
```

You can then remove all the other methods you've added such as shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation, shouldAutorotate , supportedInterfaceOrientations , preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation. 
All these methods are now all unnecessary.

**-----Edit-----**

Simply using

```
 [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait] forKey:@"orientation"];
```

in all view controllers where I need potrait will do the trick. no other things needed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, let me try this :)

Comment: Still that issue is there. :(

Comment: Ok, then add this snippet on the method viewDidLoad of SecondViewController.m : [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait] forKey:@"orientation"];

Comment: It's working now superbly in the sample project, let me integrate this in my main project. Thank you so much.